# What are things to look for when buying a new keyboard?

Tags: instruments, keyboard

I'm a complete newbie to music and I've been wanting to buy a keyboard for a while now. However, upon doing some research I was surprised at the vast amount of technical details associated with each keyboard. The more I researched on it, the more confused I became.
Does pressure sensitivity matter? Are a higher number of accompaniment voices better? Do total number of instrument voices make any differences from a learning perspective? Super confused about what I should watch out for in particular when purchasing a keyboard. I've considered either the CASIO CS-S300 or the Yamaha PSR-E373, but as I said, I'm just so lost in the details. If someone can mention what major things to look out for, it would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How do you plan to use the keyboard? Some info on your short and longer term goals, or knowing you haven't considered goals, would help get you the best advice.

Comment: @Aaron right. My short term goal is to become proficient enough to be able to play songs on it. Nothing professional, but something I can play in the house and impress some friends with.Getting really comfortable with the basics and having a good grasp so I can adapt to play the tune of any song I'd like on the keyboard. In the long term, my goal is small performances in my local community at annual functions and events.The usage is definitely casual and not professional yet.

Comment: Do you want to play it like a piano or play it like a synthesizer or like an organ or... other?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Definitely not like an organ, just a regular keyboard.

Comment: I think the point that ToddWilcox was getting at is that a piano would have weighed keys (so something that you plan too use to play piano music should probably have them too) while many other keyboard instruments wouldn't have weighed keys. Therefore you should probably think about what you plan to use it for.

Answer (score 0):

This is in danger of being closed, although you're not actually asking for specific keyboards to buy - like the vtc-ers seem to think - but in any case, you've been minimal as to what you *think* you need.

It sounds like an electronic piano would be a good bet. 61 notes should be the absolute minimum. You won't use all of them for a while, but when you do reach that stage, with fewer, you'll have to start shoppng again.

The *action* on acoustic pianos is very different from that on an organ - which has keys that are merely switches. You need a keyboard that is sensitive to how hard/soft it is played. More like a piano. There are many that have that facility, but at the same time, unless they *feel* like a piano, you'll be searching later.

The facility to change sounds is a personal thing. Some players are happy with just a piano sound, but it's fun to change to others at times. Only you will be the judge of that.

Some pianos have internal speakers, some don't. you seem like you'll need the former, and a headphone socket is a useful addition.

No recommendations here - that's off remit for this site, so you need to try out several - many - and eventually make your own wishlist. Price and portability are other aspects, but no clues from the question.

Comment: I've been thinking of that. A 61 key keyboard with sensitivity to how hard the keys are pressed. The major ones I've looked at are the casio and yamaha. So far, I've thought of the Yamaha PSR-E373, let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Like I said, no recommendations!